# Horizontal scrollbar removal in IE when using Responsive bootstrap table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I created a responsive table with bootstrap 3.3.2
The issue was the presence of horizontal scroll bar always at the bottom of the table.
As per the below link
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10711

I used container-fluid in table so the issue resolved in Crome but in IE it is still showing.
Any idea to remove horizontal scrollbar in IE when it reaches 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

change the class row by container-fluid

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="sectionLeft">
             Sidebar Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        Test content
    </div>
</div>
```